# Nativescript iOS App Signing App in Azure Devops

Tags: ios, azure-devops, nativescript

I have a pipeline that builds an ipa and an xcarchive. Currently, I have to download the xcarchive onto my Mac and open it, distribute the app and sign it using codesign. Ideally, I would like to achieve this in an Azure Devops Pipeline. Is there an easy way to distribute the xcarchive, grab the ipa, sign it and publish the ipa to the pipeline artifact?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sign app in Azure Pipelines, you could try with the Signing and provisioning options in Xcode pipeline task.

First, you could store your Apple certificate and Provisioning Profile as the [secure files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/secure-files?view=azure-devops) in Azure DevOps.

Then, you could use the [Install Apple Certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-certificate?view=azure-devops) and [Install Apple Provisioning Profile tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/install-apple-provisioning-profile?view=azure-devops) install them from the secure files and make them available to Xcode during a build.

When you use Xcode task, please fill the inputs for [Signing and provisioning options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode?view=azure-devops#signing-and-provisioning-options), such as selecting the signingoptions and other details. Meanwhile, the Xcode task also helps you build the project.

After that, you could publish the build output to your pipeline artifact.